# c# taking last 4 bytes of byte array are reversed

Tags: c#, arrays, tcp, tcplistener

I have a c# tcp socket where im getting byte stream from a hardware device.

The device is sending the following bits sequence:

[image]

```
0000000000000000101001011010010110100101101001010000000000000000000000000000000010111110101101011000100101111111
```

Where based on the message format we have:

- ID: `0000000000000000`
- ID2: `10100101101001011010010110100101`
- Payload Size: `00000000000000000000000000000000`
- Payload: `empty` (because payload size is 0)
- CRC: `10111110101101011000100101111111`

In my code I had to compute the `CRC` of the `ID + ID2 + Payload Size + Payload` so that has to match the `CRC` 4 bytes of the message.

I already did that and my computed CRC matches the message CRC, the problem is that when I try to get my message CRC 4 bytes by some reason they get in reverse order each byte.

```
//// GET RAW MESSAGE PART (without CRC) in order to calculate CRC ////
var raw = state.buffer.Take(10 + payloadLength).ToArray();
uint computedCrc = DamienG.Security.Cryptography.Crc32.Compute(raw);

var crcBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(computedCrc);
bits = new BitArray(crcBytes);
// convert to bit sequence string to see it visually
bytesToString = ToBitString(bits);

//// GET ONLY MESSAGE CRC PART so I can compare both
var messageCRC= state.buffer.Skip(10 + payloadLength).Take(4).ToArray();
bits = new BitArray(crc);
// convert to bit sequence string to see it visually
bytesToString = ToBitString(bits);
```

The first part of the code computes the `CRC` based on the raw message (without the `CRC`) and the result of `bytesToString`  is:

```
10111110 10110101 10001001 01111111
```

Which is CORRECT.

The second part of the code trys to get the last 4 bytes of the message that is the `CRC` and the result of `bytesToString` is:

```
01111101 10101101 10010001 11111110
```

> So by analyzing this last sequence, seems all good the only problem is that each byte is reversed, so I dont know why is reversed and how can I make so it looks exactly as the CRC message sequence.

**UPDATE:** THIS IS THE CRC32 CLASS IM USING

```
public sealed class Crc32 : HashAlgorithm
    {
        public const UInt32 DefaultPolynomial = 0x04C11DB7;
        public const UInt32 DefaultSeed = 0x11111111u;

        static UInt32[] defaultTable;

        readonly UInt32 seed;
        readonly UInt32[] table;
        UInt32 hash;

        public Crc32()
            : this(DefaultPolynomial, DefaultSeed)
        {
        }

        public Crc32(UInt32 polynomial, UInt32 seed)
        {
            if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Not supported on Big Endian processors");

            table = InitializeTable(polynomial);
            this.seed = hash = seed;
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            hash = seed;
        }

        protected override void HashCore(byte[] array, int ibStart, int cbSize)
        {
            hash = CalculateHash(table, hash, array, ibStart, cbSize);
        }

        protected override byte[] HashFinal()
        {
            var hashBuffer = UInt32ToBigEndianBytes(~hash);
            HashValue = hashBuffer;
            return hashBuffer;
        }

        public override int HashSize { get { return 32; } }

        public static UInt32 Compute(byte[] buffer)
        {
            return Compute(DefaultSeed, buffer);
        }

        public static UInt32 Compute(UInt32 seed, byte[] buffer)
        {
            return Compute(DefaultPolynomial, seed, buffer);
        }

        public static UInt32 Compute(UInt32 polynomial, UInt32 seed, byte[] buffer)
        {
            return ~CalculateHash(InitializeTable(polynomial), seed, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        static UInt32[] InitializeTable(UInt32 polynomial)
        {
            if (polynomial == DefaultPolynomial && defaultTable != null)
                return defaultTable;

            var createTable = new UInt32[256];
            for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                var entry = (UInt32)i;
                for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    if ((entry & 1) == 1)
                        entry = (entry >> 1) ^ polynomial;
                    else
                        entry = entry >> 1;
                createTable[i] = entry;
            }

            if (polynomial == DefaultPolynomial)
                defaultTable = createTable;

            return createTable;
        }

        static UInt32 CalculateHash(UInt32[] table, UInt32 seed, IList<byte> buffer, int start, int size)
        {
            var hash = seed;
            for (var i = start; i < start + size; i++)
                hash = (hash >> 8) ^ table[buffer[i] ^ hash & 0xff];
            return hash;
        }

        static byte[] UInt32ToBigEndianBytes(UInt32 uint32)
        {
            var result = BitConverter.GetBytes(uint32);

            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(result);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I depends on the CRC algorithm you are using.  Some CRCs algorithms reverse the CRC and others do not.  So both are correct.  Here is a very good webpage explaining CRCs : http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html  Some of the algorithms call a Reflect method which reverses the CRC.

Comment: So both are correct? At least I feel better with those words. OK I will check how the CRC algorith i have works

Comment: @jdweng I update the thread with the CRC32 code im using

Comment: Use the custom option on homepage to find out what you are doing wrong : http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html  Either you need to reflect or you are shifting right (and test LSB) when you should be shifting left and testing MSB.  I think you just need to reflect final answer.